# Tool to list all the colors used in my stylesheets?

Tags: css, color

I'm trying to cleanup the colors used on my Ember.js project so I was wondering if there is some good tool around to list all the colors used in my stylesheets?

I'm using LESS, so any tool with LESS support will be preferred.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux or something else?

Comment: I'm on Mac Yosemite